# android - I change the perspective when I turn my phone, my mediaPlayer and application stoping

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I created an application for playing media file, it's work fine. but I change the perspective when I turn my phone, my application stoping.

Answer (score 0):

When you change orientation, Android will re-create the Activity.  So, you'll need to specifically handle the orientation change by overriding the onConfigurationChanged method of your Activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   // your code here.
}
```

Comment: I do not want to apply changes to my application.